# Sparse convolution of sparse arrays

Tags: sparse-arrays, convolution

The documentation for [`ListConvolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListConvolve.html) mentions that "ListConvolve works with sparse arrays", which is true. The result, however is never sparse, eg:

```
a = SparseArray[50 -> x, 1000];
b = SparseArray[40 -> 2, 50];
ListConvolve[b, a]
```

Is there a way to do "sparse convolution"?

(The background is multiplication of high-degree many variables polynomials.)

Comment: `ListConvolve` uses Fourier transforms, and it's very difficult to achieve significantly better performance with the FFT for general sparse inputs and outputs than one can get by doing the full transform. So, while the answer to your question is certainly "yes", producing a solution is certainly more than a matter of a simple programming problem.

Comment: If these polynomials are very sparse you can perhaps do it as a sparse matrix-vector multiply, which of course will give you a sparse result. But the performance achievable in this fashion might not be very impressive.

Comment: isn't sparse multiplication with a circular matrix a convolution?

Comment: @chris, yup, but whether that route is more efficient than FFT depends on quite a lot of things...

Comment: @J.M. sure: how Sparse is the convolution to start with.

Comment: @chris The convolution is very sparse. Stupid example: `x^7 y^12 z^3`and `x^2 y^8 z^11` (represented by `8x13x4` and `3x9x12` dimensional arrays, sparse version of `CoefficientArray[]`). Using circular matrices might work but they need to be generalized to higher dimension in this context (I am convoluting arrays). I ended up doing some kind of explicit outer-product on the vectors of non-zero coefficients which might be even more efficient than a matrix-vector type of solution (in higher dimension), given the extreme sparsity. I will write it down in more details when I have the chance.

Comment: higher dimensions should not be a problem with sparse matrices though: see edit below.

Answer (score 5):

Sparse multiplication with a circular matrix corresponds to a convolution; on a trivial 
example let us compare:

```
matrix = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 2, Band[{1, 2}] -> 1, Band[{2, 1}] -> 1}, {15, 15}];


vec = SparseArray[5 -> x, 15]; matrix.vec // Normal

(* ==> {0, 0, 0, x, 2 x, x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

versus

```
a = SparseArray[5 -> x, 15] // Normal; b = {1, 2, 1};
ListConvolve[b, a]

(* ==> {0, 0, x, 2 x, x, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} *)
```

So it seems `ListConvolve` treats edges differently than circular matrix multiplication. 
Must be described in the documentation of  `ListConvolve`.

In terms of performance, the issue is how diagonal your matrix is or equivalently how long a or b is.

**EDIT**

Let's do some timing to estimate the performance of convolution as a function of 
how sparse the matrix is.
Consider a band matrix with a custom width of 2p

```
Clear[matrix];
matrix[p_, n_] := SparseArray[Join[Table[Band[{1, j}] -> 1/p, {j, 1, p}], 
    Table[Band[{j, 1}] -> 1/p, {j, 2, p}]], {n, n}];

Clear[vec]; vec[n_] := SparseArray[5 -> x, n];
```

Let us see how the time to carry out the multiplication increases with the width

```
Table[{p,matrix[p, 10000].vec[10000]; // Timing // First},{p, 2, 10}]

(*
==> ({
  {2, 0.049756},
  {3, 0.094646},
  {4, 0.141837},
  {5, 0.197723},
  {6, 0.244743},
  {7, 0.287893},
  {8, 0.344092},
  {9, 0.403023},
  {10, 0.472343}
 })
*)
```

The scaling with the width p seems to be $p^{4/3}$ 
(this includes the time to build the convolution matrix)

```
 Fit[Log10[%], {1, x}, x]

 (* ==> 1.31 x -1.65 *)
```

Of course scaling could be different if say the Arrays were made of finite precision numbers.

**EDIT 2**

Note that the method works in arbitrary dimensions; let us define a 2D convolution matrix using splines:

```
design = Table[BSplineBasis[3, (x - xi + 1/2)] BSplineBasis[
    3, (y - yi + 1/2)], {xi, 1, 5, 1/4}, {yi, 1, 5,1/4}, {x, 1, 5, 1/4}, {y, 1, 5, 1/4}];

matrix = Partition[design// Flatten, 17^2] // SparseArray;
```

(here I am just lazy; one would of course need to fill the matrix
directly as a sparse matrix).

Let us now define a 2D field

```
field = Table[If[x == 3 && y == 3, 1, 0], {x, 1, 5, 1/4}, {y, 1, 5, 1/4}];
field // MatrixPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Lets convolve this 2D field by the above defined sparsified matrix using sparse multiplication:

```
Partition[matrix.SparseArray[Flatten[field]], 17] // MatrixPlot
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]